# How can I use an input box to redirect to specific ports on same URL

Tags: html, forms, redirect, port

I'm trying to have an html input box and in that box I put a number then on submit redirect to that URL and port.

Like I'm on mysite.com which has an input box say I input 1234 and click submit it redirects to mysite.com:1234

Hope that makes sense.

Right I did try this

```
<form method="POST" action=":">
    <input type="number" name="" placeholder="Search.." />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

But I get results mysite.com:/

But need mysite.com:1234 (or what ever is input in box)

Ok this is what I have so far but probably missing something as its still not working.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // Get the value from the input field
    const port = document.getElementById('portNumber').value;
    const baseUrl = "h--ps://mysite.com";
    window.location.href = '${baseUrl}:${port}';
    
});
  </script>



<form id="myForm" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="number" name="" id="portNumber" placeholder="Port Number.." />
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Possibly not with pure HTML, you might need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // Get the value from the input field
    const port = document.getElementById('portNumber').value;
    const baseUrl = "..ht.tp://www.mysite.com" // u know what i'm trying to write, stackoverflow wont let me write http
    window.location.href = `${baseUrl}:${port}`;
    
});
```

This should work assuming your form has ID myForm. use this in your JS script.
Haven't checked whether URL is valid or not here.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I set my action to as it fails without :(

Comment: tried this ```<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='number' id='myForm' name='portNumber' placeholder='Search..' />
    <input type='submit' value='Go'/>
</form>
```

Comment: action='javascript:void(0)' should work try that

Comment: action='' will send request to same URL of the page you're on. you want to manually handle form submission so you set action as the line I typed. it will effectively do nothing.

Can you explain exactly what's happening when you submit the form? I'll be able to guide you better then.

Comment: Thanks for your help... When I Submit with void(0) it just does nothing. Keeps the number in seach box.. Added code im using to original post.. URL is not the real one btw